# Using "this" in methods in java

Tags: java

Is it still needed to use "this." to keep calling a variable in a class? For example:

```
public class APLine {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public APLine(int a, int b, int c){

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public double getSlope(){

        return (double)this.a * - 1/ this.b;
    }

    public boolean isOnLine(int x, int y){

        return this.a * x + this.b * y + this.c == 0;
    }
}
```

For the methods getSlope() and isOnLine() is it needed to code this.a, this.b, or this.c. Or is it completely unnecessary and it's okay to just use a, b, or c?

Comment: yes, it's okay to just use a, b, or c

Comment: The `this` keyword is really only needed when an ambiguous reference is being used. For example, in your constructor, you are passing an `a` variable and your class also has its own `a` variable. You use the `this` keyword to differentiate between the two.

When you move out of your constructor and into the other two methods, there is only one `a` variable in scope: the `a` for the class, so you do not need to specify `this`. Basically, the class field `a` is the only `a` your methods know about anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword `this` refers to the current instance of the class. So in your case it is not necesary to use `this.fieldName` as you do not have another variable which is shadowing the instance field.

But consider this scenario where you'd be needing to use `this`:

```
public boolean isOnLine(int a, int b){

    return this.a * a + this.b * a + c == 0;
}
```

Here the local variables `a` and `b` are shadowing the instance fields `a` and `b`. If you do not use `this`, `a` will simply refer to the local variable and not the instance field.